# In classical singing the speaking range is not a specific register. Why is this?

Tags: voice

I disslike singing in my speaking range. I feel like it is much easier to sing above the speaking range.
In classical singing the speaking range is not a specific register. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You can describe 'Speaking range' as a register if you want to.

You find it easier to sing above it.  Personally, I'd define it as the singing range which is easy, minimal effort required! But we're all different.